# Disable autocompletion in Atom

Tags: text-editor, auto-completion, atom

So I just recently got into coding (Python) and I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and the Atom text editor.

A very annoying feature is the auto-completion. For example, I type in `x` (a variable I set previously) and when I press <kbd>enter</kbd> to get to the next line, it autocompletes to `# XXX:` for some reason. That's very annoying and I want to disable that feature.

I searched the config but I couldn't find an option for that.

Can anyone help me with my problem?

Comment: Disable the `autocompletion-plus` package (https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same thing, but rather than disabling the autocomplete package you can just change the hotkey.  By default, the suggestion is autocompleted when you press either <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd> which is annoying when you press enter to get to next line.

I changed it to <kbd>tab</kbd> only so that I can still use autocomplete when it's useful, but it won't put the wrong text in place when starting a new line.

Comment: And here's how to change it to "Tab" only: adjust "Edit → Preferences → Packages → autocomplete-plus → Settings → Keymap for confirming a suggestion". It's the 4th setting from top currently.